# How to Get Value from Shared View in Main View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC.  There is a header page that shows on every page in our application as a partial view.  It contains a `@Model` called "HeaderInfoModel" which contains the UserID of the current user.  Is there a way for me to access `@Model.UserID`in the Main View? I want to send it as a paramete to a URL action on a button click in the main view.  Is this even possible?

Comment: In the case of a user ID specifically, you should be able to get from the session / http context normally (unless you have built some completely esoteric login system instead of using the framework)

Comment: Thanks.  I did not build any of it.  I think there may be something in Session.  I am looking at that.  But to answer my question, is there any way to grab that information if it is not in session?

Comment: Not from the Razor code directly, no. The model for the partial is only accessible within the partial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your _Layout.cshtml in first row Add

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

and You Can Pass the Parameter

```
@User.Identity.GetUserName()
@User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do. As you have access to the User id on the server, you can either pass it along when the main view is loaded. You can pass it as a separate model. One that is specific to the main view. Or you could pass that as a part of Viewbag etc and the read that in the main view.